# I want to know the correct left join

Tags: mysql

I have this query where I want all the records of table mstemp must be shown based on the condition given.

```
SELECT 
    mstEmp.empname, InDate, dailyattendance.InTime,
    dailyattendance.OutTime, mstEmp.teamtype 
FROM 
    mstEmp
LEFT JOIN 
    dailyattendance ON (dailyattendance.HolderName = mstEmp.empname ) 
WHERE 
    mstEmp.teamtype = '$chk' 
    AND (InDate BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' )
ORDER BY 
    InDate ASC
```

But it seems this query isn't working.

Comment: What do you mean "isn't working"? Does it give you an error? Does it show 0 results?

Comment: @cyclotrojan: The missing `O` was from my edit.

Comment: it is showing all the records of dailyattendance table but i want mstEmp records where sum values have Null value.

Comment: InDate range of date entered by user from ($from) when he wants to see the records till when($to)

Comment: If you get 0 rows and `InDate` located in `dailyattendance` table you should move this condition to join: `... from mstemp left join dailyattentandance  on (... and indate between '$from ' and '$to')`.

Comment: @ravnur tried it but i want only mstEmp records wheher they have null value or not.

Comment: Himani, I suppose nobody understands what you want to get in the result set. It would be better if you provide some data samples for 2 tables and desired result set.

Comment: this is wat i want

HolderName | Intime | outtime | team
Date: 21-06-12
abc        | NULL   | NULL    | HR
BVC        | 9.50   | 5.30    | HR 


wat i m getting is

HolderName | Intime | outtime | team
Date: 21-06-12
BVC        | 9.50   | 5.30    | HR

Comment: m not getting null value record

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT mstEmp.empname, InDate, dailyattendance.InTime,
       dailyattendance.OutTime, mstEmp.teamtype 
FROM mstEmp
  LEFT JOIN dailyattendance 
    ON (dailyattendance.HolderName = mstEmp.empname ) AND (InDate BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' )
WHERE mstEmp.teamtype = '$chk' 
ORDER BY InDate ASC
```

Comment: not working. & wat changes dd u do its seems like the previous

Comment: moving the condition from where to on clausel does not change the result

Comment: i want if there is sum entry in mstEmp and not in dailattendence then it should show those results with null values

Comment: guys solution to the quetsion?

Comment: try to remove the where condition ?

Comment: remove 2 conditions in **your** query, do you see any result with null value?
"The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all the rows from the left table (mstEmp), even if there are no matches in the right table (dailyattendance)."
"

Comment: you tell me which one 2 remove as i tried bur m nt getting the desried result.

Comment: tried it but i want only mstEmp records wheher they have null value or not.

Comment: do you see allrecord that you desired when query:
`SELECT mstEmp.empname, InDate, dailyattendance.InTime,
       dailyattendance.OutTime, mstEmp.teamtype 
FROM mstEmp
  LEFT JOIN dailyattendance 
    ON (dailyattendance.HolderName = mstEmp.empname ) 
ORDER BY InDate ASC`
if yes, add WHERE conditions to get what you want, else, you have other problem

check this `SELECT *
FROM hvnleft
LEFT JOIN hvnjoin ON ( hvnleft._id = hvnjoin._id )
on this db http://pastebin.com/mvADPFUt

Comment: this is wat i want HolderName | Intime | outtime | team Date: 21-06-12 abc | NULL | NULL | HR BVC | 9.50 | 5.30 | HR wat i m getting is HolderName | Intime | outtime | team Date: 21-06-12 BVC | 9.50 | 5.30 | HR   m not getting null value record

Comment: can you give a dump of two that tables? I will try on it.

Comment: i meant the dump file from that two tables, and then I can try them on my computer

Comment: Table: dailyattendence
cardno | HolderName | InDate     | InTime     | Outtime 
 10    | abc        | 2012-06-11 | 1174484736 | 1174484790  

Table: mstEmp
carno  | empname  | teamtype
10     | abc      | HR

Comment: it must be not null because it pass your condition.
dailyattendance.HolderName = mstEmp.empname 
dailyattendance.abc = mstEmp.abc

Comment: so wat should i do i need these conditions

Comment: i don't really know what you want to do, but if you want to get : 21-06-12 abc | NULL | NULL | HR, try to delete this record: `dailyattendence cardno | HolderName | InDate | InTime | Outtime 10 | abc | 2012-06-11 | 1174484736 | 1174484790`